# What are some tokens that are equivalent to "$" for assembly language code?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am still new at assembly language.  I find that frequently using"$" slows down my typing speed because i have to "shift 4" so many times. I am curious to know if there is an equivalent token that I could use.

Or maybe perhaps there is a way for me to program one of my keyboard keys to give me the character "$" so that i don't always have to "shift 4".

Please let me know what you think, and i appreciate your inputs!

Comment: if you want $ on a separate key, create a new keyboard layout for your own, or use a tool to remap the keys. Another way is using a scripting tool like autohotkey

Answer (score 2):

Whether there's an equivalent token depends on your assembler, but it's unlikely. Here are four solutions:

- Use a macro preprocessor (like `m4` on Unix/Linux) to turn some other string into `$` before passing the source code to your assembler. If you're already running your source code through the C preprocessor, use `#define`s. E.g. `#define ra0 $a0`.
- Learn how to set up macros in your text editor so you can, say, type <kbd>\ a 0</kbd> and have your editor replace it with `$a0`.
- Type `remap keys windows` or `remap keys linux` or `remap keys mac` into your favorite search engine to find a way to remap, at the operating system level, some other key combination to `$`. You might have to buy an app to set this up, particularly on Windows or macOS.
- Learn to type better. The correct way to type `$` is to press the right <kbd>shift</kbd> with your right pinky, and press <kbd>4</kbd> with your left index finger. If you're typing it any other way, practice typing it correctly. In particular, if you're using the left <kbd>shift</kbd>, you're probably contorting your left hand into an awkward position every time you type `$`.